# Append HTML block to an element with lowest value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table:

```
<table id="sortme">
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="50"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="20"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

With the following script:

```
$(function () {
  $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"])').sort(function(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
  }).appendTo('#sortme');
});
```

The table will be re-sorted so that the second row, will become the first one, since `20 < 50`.

Question:

In addition to that, how can I also append an HTML block right after the `[input]` that was found as the lowest, and reach this result:

```
<table id="sortme">
      <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="20"/> 
        <p class="min">Min. Value</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="50"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I guess I should add some `.appendTo("input[name='pr']")` command as the last row to the script, but not sure how to do it.

**Edit:**

While Sachin's Solution is Good, I would also like to see a solution that appends the block to the lowest value, and will be independent of the first function which sorts the table. the reason is that I might want to append the block without doing any sorting.

Comment: How about `.appendTo("input[name='pr']:first")` ?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov, maybe he needs `:first`

Comment: @mickro Yes, true  ))

Comment: I've edited my question - I would like to see a solution that can be independent of the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.. if you want to do it without sort:

```js
$(function () {
  var min = $("#sortme input[name='pr']:first").val()
  $("#sortme input[name='pr']").each(function(){
       if(parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt(min))
           min = $(this).val();
  });
$('<p class="min">Min. Value</p>').insertAfter("#sortme input[name='pr'][value='" + min + "']:first");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sortme" border="1|0">
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="50"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="20"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

or this with sort:

after sorting.. this will insert p tag after first input of table, as after sorting the minimum value will be on top.

```
$('<p class="min">Min. Value</p>').insertAfter("#sortme input:first");
```

Appending it before sort will not solve the purpose because you won't be very sure about where is the minimum value, in the last, in the top or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! seems to work, should be   `$('<p class="min">Min. Value</p>').insertAfter("table input[name='pr']:first");` to be exact, as I mighy have more inputs in other cells.

Comment: After rethinking a bit, I'm looking for an additional answer, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"])').sort(function(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
  }).appendTo('#sortme').first().find("input[name='pr']").after('<p class="min">Min. Value</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First search the input with least value:

```
var minValue = Math.min.apply( null, $("input[name='pr']").map(function(){return this.value;}) );
```

Then append to input with this value:

```
.appendTo("input[value='" + minValue + "']")
```